# How to use git clone with ssh protected gitolite server

Tags: git, ubuntu, azure, ssh, gitolite

I have set up gitolite on Azure Cloud according to these article: https://www.devbridge.com/articles/create-your-own-git-server-on-azure-cloud/

Now I want to clone the gitolite-admin repo, but I'm having problem with access.

My virtual machine is set up to allow for ssh2 connection and when I want to clone the gitolite-admin repo on my home computer (Windows) I need to provide the right key for it.

When I type from git bash

```
git clone git@my-server:gitolite-admin
```

I get

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

I think I'm little bit lost in these public-private keys.

I've generated according to these key for my Azure VM
http://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-use-ssh-key/

Then I've uploaded admin.cer to my Azure

I can connect with putty, filezilla, everything works.

I've generated admin.pub with puttygen and uploaded it to the server.

Then I've done this

```
ssh-keygen -i -f /tmp/ssh2/admin.pub > /tmp/openssh/admin.pub
```

in order to make it work with gitolite.

I've setup gitolite with these key and now I can't clone it.

I think I just need to hook up somehow my original private key to use with git clone but have no idea how.

I've already put all of these keys to my `%HOMEPATH%/.shh/` folder but it doesn't worked.

I've even set up `%HOME% = %HOMEPATH%` as an enviromental variable in Windows.

Now I'm truly lost with everything I've done.

Comment: I've ended up using GitLab so nevermind, but i'm still confused about public/private key thing, and i'd like to now it better, so if someone could have explain this it'll be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to do 2 things.

First, ensure that the properties on your .ssh directory and files in there are correct. ssh is very picky about this  `~/.ssh` should be dwrx------, the private key should be -rw------, public key at least -rw-r--r--.

The second one, is to make sure that you admin private key is presented when connecting to the the server. Since you didn't use a default key name, I would recommend to create a `config` file in `.ssh` that contains the following lines (defining a myserver alias):

```
host myserver
user git
hostname my-server
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/admin
```

and try to clone using this alias with `git clone myserver:gitoline-admin`.